# DOM script insertion

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, ooyala

I have been meaning to insert a small script into the DOM at runtime in order to load a video player. but the player gets loaded in all different places except the `<div>` where i want it to be. i dont understand how to deal with this. 
i am pasting the entire code here. please help me out.

```
<html>
<head><title>video test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="swf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
//  debugger;
    var template = $('<div class="sResult"><div class="figure"></div><div class="title"></div></div>');
    var url = 'http://player.ooyala.com/player.js?width=320&amp;height=240&amp;embedCode=thbXMxMzpq0RhOS82Hzx1lma8UMnFN-3&amp;callback=apicallback';
    var tempScript = document.createElement('script');
    tempScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    tempScript.src = url;

    $("#main").append(template);


    $("div.figure", $('#main')).html(tempScript);
    $("div.title", $('#main')).append("testkjdfnkjdb");

})
</script>   

</head>
<body>
    <div id="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

the append procedure for `div.title` is working fine. but the `div` in which i am trying to append the video player is not working correctly. the video player is getting appended to the `<head>`

**EDIT:** can some javascript guru please look into the player.js and tell me why isn't it working for me?

the player `<div>` contains the following:

```
<div style="width: 320px; height: 240px; overflow: hidden;" id="ooyalaPlayer6764909_10qreejOoyalaPlayerOutterWrapper"><object width="320" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="ooyalaPlayer6764909_10qreej" class="OoyalaVideoPlayer" data="http://player.ooyala.com/static/cacheable/fb1a00342b9ec2d6df7c69946617dcee/player_v2.swf"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000"><param name="wmode" value="window">
<param name="flashvars"></object></div>
```

Comment: What does your player.js script do?

Comment: You're mixing javascript node creation with jQuery node creation.  Picking one method will help you to see your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also provide the Ooyala player with a targetReplaceId=(element id) query string parameter to force it to replace an item on page.

Answer (score 1):

First fix your URL, passing the `playerId` param.

```
    var url = 'http://player.ooyala.com/player.js?playerId=player&width=320&amp;height=240&amp;embedCode=thbXMxMzpq0RhOS82Hzx1lma8UMnFN-3&amp;callback=apicallback';
```

Create an listener for tempScript loader and append the player script to the header:

```
$(tempScript).load(function() {
     $('#main').find('div.figure').append($('head>div'));
});
$('head')[0].appendChild(tempScript);
```

In the listener move the content from player where you want just re-append it.

I supose that the problem is in the player.js, not where you attach the script loader.

Ooyala API Docs: http://ooyala.com/support/docs/player_api#javascript

Comment: the text in the title is getting appended just fine. by your approach and by my approach. but the video player is getting appended in the <head> section

Comment: And if you try a appendChild, like: $(template).find("div.figure")[0].appendChild(tempScript); but I supose that the problem is inside your player.js file... What the ID from player element that is appended to <HEAD>?

Comment: the id of the player element appended to head is "ooyalaPlayer6764909_10qreejOoyalaPlayerOutterWrapper"

Comment: It have any other identifier, like a class, or a div, or player element?

Comment: i have edited the question to include teh generated player's HTML code

Comment: Try instead $('player') this: $('head>div'), and see what you get, or use the player API: http://www.ooyala.com/support/docs/player_api#javascript

Comment: it still isnt getting appended to the <div>

Answer (score -1):

Your selector is wrong:

```
$("#main div.figure").html(tempScript);
```

etc..

Comment: that was not the point. the point is the DOM insertion of the script.

Comment: Yes, and your selector is wrong, it is incorrect jQuery syntax.